# Database existence not happened correctly

Tags: sql-server

I am having problems running a SQL script to `CREATE` a database on SQL Server 2014.

My script fails with the following error, however I am not sure how to resolve the issue as I am a beginner with SQL Server.

```
CREATE DATABASE [BIDS] 
  CONTAINMENT = NONE ON PRIMARY 
  ( NAME = N'BIDS', 
    FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\BIDS.mdf' , 
    SIZE = 4096KB , 
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, 
    FILEGROWTH = 1024KB 
  ) 
  LOG ON 
  ( NAME = N'BIDS_log', 
    FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\BIDS_log.ldf' , 
    SIZE
    ---
```

What should I do to resolve this error?

> Msg 1803, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The CREATE DATABASE statement failed. The primary file must be at least 5 MB to accommodate a copy of the model database.
>
> Msg 5011, Level 14, State 5, Line 11
>   User does not have permission to alter database 'BIDS', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like someone changed the defaults that exist in the model database on the server (512 is usually the default from what I've seen--not 4096). Since this is for a deployment on possibly any SQL Server (where model specifications could well be different) just remove the SIZE = 4096KB in both the mdf and ldf sections--to avoid this issue altogether. Each SQL Server will create the database based on specifications of the model database on SQL Server.

Example:

```
CREATE DATABASE [BIDS] CONTAINMENT = NONE 
ON PRIMARY ( NAME = N'BIDS', FILENAME = N'C:\temp\BIDS.mdf' ,  
  MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) 
LOG ON ( NAME = N'BIDS_log', FILENAME = N'C:\temp\BIDS_log.ldf' ,  
  MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB)
```